# I keep getting the same error when trying to clip a raster

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

Error: Cutline feature without a geometry.

Consistently get the above error when trying to clip a raster. I have looked at all the other questions relating to this and tried all the 'fixes' however I am still getting the same error. Anything I may have overlooked.

There are no errors when validating the polygon and both polygon and raster are in the same CRS - WGS84 / UTM 37S

Answer (score 1):

No worries - I have done it via converting polygon to a raster and multiplying by the original raster. Then removing the black in the transparency tab of properties.

If anyone else has a similar problem this works!